# Rails joins where pluck returns type rather than a value

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Running the query

`

```
Profile.joins(:values).where("profiles.bill * values.data > 200").pluck(:bill)
```

returns `Object #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fcf5175b6b0>`

However I would like to receive an array of bills from that query.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Rails lazy loading, its kinda of like a pointer, add

```
.all
```

to the query and you will get actual instance arrays

Comment: No, mate, I should be to run `Person.pluck(:id)` on a model rather than on an array of objects source:http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck

Comment: sorry about that, I did not know about the pluck method.